# Windows Server 2022 on HP Enterprise Proliant ML350 gets black screen after RDP services enabled

Tags: hp-proliant

I've setup Remote Desktop Services on HPE Proliant ML350 Gen10 Windows Server 2022.

After server restarted, when logged in as admin user only mouse pointer and black screen appears. It only allows to do CTRL+ALT+DEL but only logoff function is working, task manager is not working.

Server is HP Enterprise Proliant ML350 Gen10 , less than 1 year old. I configured RDP services to enable remote desktop connections to client machines.

For clarity it's ML350 GEN10 server , I am not able to login as Admin to restart RDP services since as soon as I logged in black screen appears.

Server is now stuck and unable to do anything.

I will provide as much information.

It's with ilo 5 configuration but I was not able to do ILO login via Browser before this error happens.

My task is to create domain controller and assign the clients to the server.
Which I have done and network was working with the server having static IP however
when I try to use a client PC to connect to the server it said RDP
licensing server is not available. Then I login to the server itself as Admin and setup the the remote desktop services via feature. Once done I have restated the server manually and was able to login as Admin again but it came up with black screen.

It only allows to do CTL+ALT+DEL but task manger did not appear as well when clicked.

Only option is to shut down. Therefore I doubt it's s network issue but rather to do with resources.( I may be wrong)
I am wondering is it anything to do with  HPE ProLiant Gen10 Workload Profiles

My plan is to go back to the previous good configuration, Since all is working fine before RDP services setup, Is their way to go back to the previous good configuration. I tried F8 while restating server 2022 but didn't get it, Can I use intelligent provisioning to do that? Or even reinstall server 2022, When I take over the machine it was all setup except the domain controller. –

The other option I am thinking is to change the Workload Profiles in the machine setup to High Performance Compute (HPC). If I do that can I revert it if nothing happens

Comment: Why are you re-asking this question with no additional information? There's no details on the Support Pack installed, ILO configuration, or any network details at all, which is odd considering it is likely a network issue. This question could be about any topic and still be unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you ,I've updated the information please check and let me know any feedback.

Comment: Searching for `rdp black screen` yields tons of results, even official KB articles by Microsoft. What did you already try to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you are unable to connect to the main tool that would be useful for pursuing the issue (ILO) you aren't going to get very far.

Comment: My plan is to go back to the previous good configuration, Since all is working fine before RDP services setup, Is their way to go back to the previous good configuration. I tried F8 while restating server 2022 but didn't get it, Can I use intelligent provisioning to do that? Or even reinstall server 2022, When I take over the machine it was all setup except the domain controller.

Comment: The other option I am thinking is to change the Workload Profiles in the machine setup to High Performance Compute (HPC). If I do that can I revert it if nothing happens.